# Mass of a region intuition

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

So what from what I understand

- Two integrals: The volume underneath a surface

$$$$

Now in this course they define it like so

- Let $z = f(x, y)$ be a surface and let R be a region in the $xy$ plane, where $R$ is the projection of surface z onto the $xy$ plane
- Area of a region in the $xy$ plane corresponds to the case where $f(x ,y) = 1$ and hence,  $R$ = $\int\int dR$

$$$$
How can this be the area of something? Two integrals indicate a volume, in this description above, it indicates a flat shape with a thickness of 1, hence, 3D

They then say mass of a region in the $xy$ plane with mass per unit area $\rho(x ,y)$ is $$R = \int \int \rho dR$$

which would only make sense if it was 3D, but how do you have a mass of a region, where a region is a 2D planar shape?

$$$$
So if two integrals represent the volume beneath an area, 3 integrals represents the hypervolume in the 4th dimension underneath a 3D object?

$$$$
But then they state: "The *volume* of a solid region V in $R^3$ corresponds to the case where $f(x, y, z)$ = 1, so volume of $$V = \int \int \int dx dy dz$$
From what I understand, the outcome of this integral should be 4D

$$$$
I'm sure I've gotten something very wrong, but this is incredibly confusing so if anyone can explain this it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: It's because philosophically your conception of an integral, and fundamentally what is a function, has to change. We often associate functions with their graphs, but a function * is not * its graph. A helpful way to think of a (scalar) function is that it is just rule that associates some value to a point in space. This value could be thought of as a "height above" that point, but that adds a lot of unnecessary baggage to the idea of a function. An integral is simply collecting those values and summing up the associated area of the region. So a $1$D integral is a length, $2$D integral an area.